# Cannot create release apk in Android Studio 2.2

Tags: android, apk, release

I followed come tutorials about building my apk file.
I can generate the debug apk file, but not the release one.

But, when I try to generate a signed apk, i get the following error message:

> Error:(53, 19) No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'menu' with value '@menu/activity_main_drawer').
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
>
> > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
> >     'C:\Users\Diego\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.3\aapt.exe''
> >     finished with non-zero exit value 1

I believe there is nothing wrong with my activity_main_drawer.xml file:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_distance"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_directions"
            android:title="Distance Threshold" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_clear_map"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"
            android:title="Clear Map" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

Here my folder structure:

[image]

Folder structure with res folder on detail:

[image]

Could you guys help me how to search for a solution?

Thank you

Comment: try to clean the project.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I have already done that.

Comment: Where is your activity_main_drawer.xml located?

Comment: it is localated at "res\menu\activity_main_drawer". I can debug the app on my phone, I just cannot generate the release apk. Also: there is a (debug) in gray besides the file name. Is it the problem? How can I generate a release version of the file?

Comment: It looks like the problem is related to setting the files to the wrong project schema. My AndroidManifest is on main, but only resources on debug folder are able to retrieve namespace on xmlns:android. Do you have any clue of what I am missing?

Comment: you have a folder in your "res/layout" folder. that works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Switch from Android view to Project view. Navigate to

> app --> src --> debug --> res --> menu

. Move your activity_main_drawer.xml file from this location to

> app --> src --> main --> res --> menu

.

In your current setup you have your resource files setup for debug build and not common build. Anything you move to "main" will be shared by all the builds

Comment: I did this, but all my resources now get a message "URI is not registered", and my AndroidManifest is also on main. Is there any other configuration that I am missing?

Comment: can you post a screen shot of the folder structure

Comment: Can I have a look at expanded res folder. build folder can be ignored

Comment: Added the res folder details on the question.

Comment: everything looks normal. you tried doing a clean build? what exactly is the error when you try to build it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121445/discussion-between-diego-volpato-and-rakesh-kashyap).

Answer (score 0):

```
release {
            lintOptions {
                checkReleaseBuilds false
                disable 'MissingTranslation'
            }
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
```